# How to utilize Compression and Expansion of Matter and of Time-Space outside of combat

Tags: magic, medieval, abilities

Someone has a magic power that allows them to compress and expand matter and time-space.

You are not strong enough to create blackhole but you can almost make one.

Mass remains the same to preserve the law of conservation of mass.

The compression and expansion is permanent until you modify it otherwise

How do you utilize such an ability?

- Survival
- Fun
- Comfort
- Your own prosperity

Scenario is that you're stuck in the middle ages where magic instead of technology is prevalent.

The catch is you have to hide your identity as an ability user as that would lead to your guaranteed death or suffering or at the very least forced servitude

Comment: Could you elaborate on the compression of time-space? Do you mean that anything that passes through this area grows or shrinks as if under a 3D lens? Does the compressed area stay fixed completely or does it move relative to the object upon which the compression of time-space occurred? Could you elaborate on compressed time and what that does? ----- Still interesting ability, could just use some extra info.

Comment: It shrinks like that in the 3d lens.

For compressed and expanded time simply that theres time dilation happening. A second that is happening for an hour or an hour happening in a second

@Zxyrra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability you have mentioned, would make the person a demigod in the eyes of the people. ***Nobody*** can harm a person wielding such power. In fact even modern armies would be powerless against a mage being able to compress matter to *near blackhole* levels. Here is why:

## Survival

If you can *almost* create a backhole with your ability to compress matter, then using it as a weapon (for survival situations) is very easy. The next thing to a blackhole is a neutron star which has matter compressed so densely that its core consists of neutrons only. It is the impossibly high gravity of the neutron star which keeps matter compressed so hard. If a small object (like a small ball) is compressed so hard that its atomic structure is crushed to neutrons, then releasing this compression would result in a ... (drum roll) ... nuclear blast as neutrons split up into electrons and protons, releasing the remaining part of mass as energy.

So yes, it is very easy to use this ability for survival purposes. You can actually annihilate an entire city very easily by first concentrating a football sized rock into neutron star compression level and then releasing your compression. For self defense (defense against multiple hostiles) simply compressing matter so that the atoms come really close to each other, and then releasing the compression, would create an explosion enough to annihilate a battalion sized army.

However, these are explosions too powerful for normal self defense scenarios. Usually you would want to simply keep a small steel ball full of water with you. When you want to create a moderate sized explosion, simply throw the ball at the hostiles and quickly compress the water inside the ball. It will heat up the water incredibly, so that when you release the compression, it will immediately turn into vapor/steam and the pressure would create a grenade-level explosion.

Just make sure you wield this immense power upon matter when you are far, far away from ground zero (place where the explosion occurs). The shockwave of the above mentioned explosions would be enough to level cities to ground and flatten forests.

## Fun

- Simply compress the space between two objects to make them come closer.
- Or expand the space between them to make them go farther.
- Or very slowly compress the matter of an object to make it smaller. Make sure you do not compress it too strongly, or its chemical bonds would snap or change, changing it irreversibly.

## Comfort

- You can easily warm up water or air in winter by compressing them.
- Make comfortable couches for yourself anywhere by expanding a solid object several times its original volume, making it poofy.
- Cool the air in summer by expanding it.

## Own Prosperity

- You can start a business of providing warm water to your townspeople during winter. All you would need to do is to spread a web of water pipes through the city. Your ability to compress matter would do the rest.
- You can also start a business of leveling mountains for laying the foundation of new towns etc. You would simply compress a tiny mass (a few hundred grams) at the root of the mountain to extreme levels and then release the contraction to create a colossal blast, breaking the mountain.

Comment: Just to expand on the "Fun" portion, expanding and collapsing spacetime means this guy would basicallt be his out fowm of Alcubierre Drive - he's be able to achieve FTL travel.

Comment: Haha! Yes indeed! I wonder if it comes under _fun_ part or some truly monstrous ability to rule all Earth. @IStanley

Comment: @YoustayIgo It is the fun part...

Answer (score 1):

Survival and prosperity:

First blow up a nearby mountain in broad daylight with king/ruler/etc watching.

Hand over your city or your next.

1. They agree, you rule, and you cancel stupid anti-tech magic laws.
2. No, blow up their city (or military part of it) wait for surrender, if any one is left. Hopefully carefully targeted explosions can reduce civilian death totals.  If not, oh well, kings had armies kill plenty of civilians and etc.

No one left to oppose you.... You Rule.

SUCCESS!!!

By order of the ME your new king!

- Magic is legal.
- You can't discriminate against magic users.
- Magic users have same rights and privileges as normal people.

Mobs of civilians trying to attack me will be blasted.

Option 2  Ally with king

Do you want to win every battle with minimum causalities?
   Here are my requests

- **insert your list here**

  2 Armies line up to do battle to make it look good so they aren't expecting, and you step forward and compress and launch hyper compressed material at them and they are destroyed at distance.
  Do this a few times, and the king will be happy indeed.  He can save loads of money on giant armies, and maybe have a few hundred on hand.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are looking for low profile things. 
lock your door by expanding it until it is stuck in the door frame then shrink it when you want to leave.

may a fortune as an artisan or by expanding the object while you work on it then shrinking it when you're done, making it look like you can do impossibly detailed work. you could do the same as a lens-maker to make nearly scratch free lenses.

amuse himself by making lead float or slightly shrinking the shoes of people he doesn't like.